# When piping from another command, limit the original pattern space to the matched string

Tags: linux, sed, string

I have a text file where I want to replace all spaces inside `[[` and `]]` with hyphens (brackets are never nested and always matched). The following is an example:

```
$ cat test.txt 
abc [[foo]] xyz
abc [[foo bar]] xyz
abc [[foo bar baz]] xyz [[something else]]
```

So the desired output is:

```
abc [[foo]] xyz
abc [[foo-bar]] xyz
abc [[foo-bar-baz]] xyz [[something-else]]
```

I thought I could use `sed` to match the string inside the brackets and then use the `e` flag to run the result through `sed` again to make the replacement. However the problem is that not only the matched string gets executed as a command, but the whole pattern space (which seems to be the entire line):

```
$ sed -E 's@(\[\[)(.+)(\]\])@sed -e "s/ /-/g" <<< "\1\2\3"@gpe' test.txt 
abc sed -e "s/ /-/g" <<< "[[foo]]" xyz
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

abc sed -e "s/ /-/g" <<< "[[foo bar]]" xyz
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

abc sed -e "s/ /-/g" <<< "[[foo bar baz]]" xyz
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Is there a way to limit what gets executed via the `e` flag to the matched string? If not, how would I solve this problem with `sed`?

Comment: @Quasímodo It doesn't have to be `sed`, anything that's available on the Linux command line works (however I was curious if there's a way to solve it with `sed`). There will be no imperfect strings and no nesting, i.e. every `[[` will be followed by some English words (including `'`) and then `]]`. Same for `]]`, it will never occur without a preceding `[[`.

Comment: Can you ever have more than one `[[ ]]` on a single line? Something like `aa [[foo-bar]] bb [[baz-bar]]`?

Comment: @terdon Yes that is possible, there can be many `[[ ... ]]` on the same line.

Comment: Yes, pelase [edit] your question and make sure the example you give us covers all the cases we need to deal with. Having more than one set of `[[ ]]` per line changes everything, for example, and makes some solutions unusable.

Comment: @terdon Okay thanks for the hint, I didn't know newline characters would be so special to the command line tools.

Comment: Wait, newlines? That's even more complicated! Most tools assume records (lines) are defined by a `\n` character. So if you need to consider multiple lines as a single record, that changes everything all over again.

Comment: @terdon Okay perhaps there's some confusion (on my side), so I'll state the problem as generally as possible (what I hoped to achieve with the first sentence of my question): I have a text file (utf-8 encoded) and there's a bunch of characters inside (or code points?). Now I need to replace every space ` ` (simple space, i.e. not non-breaking space, tab, etc.) inside `[[` and `]]` with a hyphen-minus `-`. The only constraint is that `[[` and `]]` are always matched and never nested. I know my 3-line example file is not exhaustive but if it meant to be, it would probably be 100+ lines.

Comment: OK, so you don't need to treat newlines in any special way then. Good :) In that case, steeldriver's solution should work just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to limit what's passed to the shell by the `e` modifier; however you could do something like this:

```
$ sed -E ':a;s@(.*\[\[)([^][]* [^][]*)(\]\].*)@printf "%s%s%s" "\1" "$(printf "\2" | sed "s/ /-/g")" "\3"@e;ta' test.txt
abc [[foo]] xyz
abc [[foo-bar]] xyz
abc [[foo-bar-baz]] xyz [[something-else]]
```

Note that handling of multiple replacements is done via a loop - and due to the greediness of the match, it actually makes the substitutions in reverse order.

Note also that `e` uses `/bin/sh` which will likely not support the `<<<` input redirection (hence the use of the piped equivalent `printf "\2" | sed "s/ /-/g"`).

---

If perl is an option you could do something closer to your original intent ex.:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=\[\[)(.*?)(?=\]\])/$1 =~ s: :-:rg/ge' test.txt
abc [[foo]] xyz
abc [[foo-bar]] xyz
abc [[foo-bar-baz]] xyz [[something-else]]
```

Since perl provides a non-greedy modifier `?`, this can handle multiple replacements per line more conventionally using the `g` flag on the outer substitution.

Comment: Thanks, the Perl example looks very nice. I'm not familiar with Perl, so could you briefly explain what the `=~` part means? Is it something like a lambda function that transforms the first capture group (`$1`) by using the r.h.s. regex (`s: :-:rg`)? Where could I read more about this (transformations of capture groups)?

Comment: @a_guest `=~` is the match operator. Here, `$1` is what was captured by the regex (the equivalent to `\1` in `sed`). The value stored in `$1` is then matched (`=~`) against a substitution operator (`s:old:new:`, this is the same in `sed`, it's just using `:` instead of `/`) which replaces all spaces with `-`. Think of the whole thing as "find the strings inside double brackets, and replace them with themselves after passing the matched string through the substitution operator which will replace the spaces".

Comment: ... and just to add to that, the outer substitution could be written using an explicit `=~` operator as well i.e. `$_ =~ s/(?<=\[\[)(.*?)(?=\]\])/$1 =~ s: :-:rg/ge` if that makes it any clearer

Answer (score 2):

Using standard `sed`:

```
$ sed -e ':again' -e 's/\(\[\[[^]]*\) \([^]]*\]\]\)/\1-\2/g' -e 't again' file
abc [[foo]] xyz
abc [[foo-bar]] xyz
abc [[foo-bar-baz]] xyz [[something-else]]
```

This replaces every space character found between `[[` and `]]` by a dash.  This is done by matching the `[[` and the `]]`, and in-between these match a space character optionally flanked by some other string.  The matched substring is the replaced as is, with the space replaced by a dash.

If a replacement is done, the `t` command makes the script branch back to the `again` label for another substitution.  This takes care of spaces missed the first time around due to overlapping matches.

Since it's stated that each `[[` is always paired with `]]` (presumably *on the same line*), we can shorten the command slightly:

```
sed -e ':again' -e 's/\(\[\[[^]]*\) /\1-/g' -e 't again' file
```

This does not look for the closing `]]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat - <<\! > file
Abc [[ \ ]] def and a cup of 
Ghi [[]] jkl 
Mno [[ ]] pqr 
abc [[" \' \\\"]] xyz
abc [[foo$$]] xyz [[a b c]] deal
abc [[foo bar]] xyz
abc [[foo bar baz]] xyz
abc [[foo $bar baz]] xyz [[FOO BAR VAZ]] $#
!
```

1. `GNU sed` without recourse to the `/e` modifier

```
sed -Ee '
  :loop
    s/([[]{2}[^][]*) ([^]]*]])/\1-\2/
  t loop
' file
```

Although it is trivial to write it Posixly, but to minimize the backslashes we use with extended regex mode enabled, `-E`. The loop progressively converts a space character / iteration found between the `[[...]]`` pair. The looping stops when it can't find any such spaces in any pair. Then the pattern space is printed nd reads the next line into the pattern space... rinse...repeat till we see the eof.

---

2. With the `awk` utility by splitting each line on the strings `[[` | `]]`. We can afford to do it bcoz of the symmetry ([[ n ]]) come in pairs and in this order. No dangling [[ or ]]. Then every even numbered field will be inside [[ n ]] and needs to be processed.

```
awk -F '[[]{2}|]]' '
  {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) {
      gsub(/ /, "-", $i)
      $i = "[[" $i "]]"
    }
  }1
' OFS= file
```

---

3.`GNU sed` using the `/e` modifier.

```
sed -Ee "
  s/'/&\"&\"&/g;tloop
  :loop
    s|(.*[[]{2})([^][]* [^]]*)(]].*)|v='\2';v=\${v// /-};printf '%s' '\1' \"\$v\" '\3'|e
  t loop
" file
```

---

4. Using perl along the same lines as awk above.

```
perl -F'(\[\[|]])' -lane 'my $i;
  print map { ++$i%4 == 3 ? tr/ /-/r : $_ } @F;
' file
```

---

5. GNU sed by means of chopping [[...]] pair, do the transformation on the isolated pair, and merge it back. Keep doing till every pair has been looked at.

```
m='[^\n]'
sed -Ee "
  s/[[]{2}|]]/&\n/g;T;h
  :loop
    s/^$m*\n($m*)\n.*/\1/
    y/ /-/;G
    s/^($m*)\n($m*)\n$m*\n/\2\1/
    h
  /\n/b loop
" file
```

---

**Output:**

```
Abc [[-\--]] def 
Ghi [[]] jkl 
Mno [[-]] pqr 
abc [["-\'-\\\"]] xyz
abc [[foo$$]] xyz [[a-b-c]] deal
abc [[foo-bar]] xyz
abc [[foo-bar-baz]] xyz
abc [[foo-$bar-baz]] xyz [[FOO-BAR-VAZ]] $#
```